# .NET Core 5.0 EF Migration add new foreign column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

I have an application with .net core Entity Framework code first.

I have 2 tables in relationships.
altKategori and anaKategori

altKategoris

```
public class altKategori
{
    [Key]
    public int idAltKategori { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Varchar")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string adAltKategori { get; set; }

    public int idAnaKategori { get; set; }
    public anaKategori anaKategori { get; set; }
}
```

anaKategoris

```
public class anaKategori
{
    [Key]
    public int idAnaKategori { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Varchar")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string adAnaKategori { get; set; }

    public List<altKategori> altKategoris { get; set; }
}
```

Also there is my Context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=.\\MSSQLSERVER2019;database=deneme;User ID=deneme1;Password=****;");
    }
    public DbSet<altKategori> altKategoris { get; set; }
    public DbSet<anaKategori> anaKategoris { get; set; }
}
```

When I start migration, migration automatic add anaKategoriidAnaKategori columns, and add relationship with that column.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "altKategoris",
            columns: table => new
            {
                idAltKategori = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                adAltKategori = table.Column<string>(type: "Varchar(30)", maxLength: 30, nullable: true),
                idAnaKategori = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                anaKategoriidAnaKategori = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_altKategoris", x => x.idAltKategori);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_altKategoris_anaKategoris_anaKategoriidAnaKategori",
                    column: x => x.anaKategoriidAnaKategori,
                    principalTable: "anaKategoris",
                    principalColumn: "idAnaKategori",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

I don't want to relation with anaKategoriidAnaKategori. I want to relation with idAnaKategori. How can I?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think EF Core will assume that some property is primary or foreign key [if it ends with `Id`](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions). So, in your case either try renaming your keys or configure the relationship in `OnModelCreating` method in `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add relation attributes

```
public class altKategori
{
    [Key]
    public int idAltKategori { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Varchar")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string adAltKategori { get; set; }

    public int idAnaKategori { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(idAnaKategori ))]
    [InverseProperty("altKategoris")]
    public anaKategori anaKategori { get; set; }
}

public class anaKategori
{
    [Key]
    public int idAnaKategori { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Varchar")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string adAnaKategori { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty(nameof(altKategori.anaKategori))]
    public List<altKategori> altKategoris { get; set; }
}
```